# How to convert string that contains only characters and numbers in scala?

Tags: regex, string, scala

I have String of characters, numbers, symbols and slashes. I want to remove everything else except characters and number

my String is like `val mystring="abd@1098\jaka.kdcs"`

I want only `abd1098jakakdcs`

Comment: Match all except what you want to match using a negated character class and replace with an empty string `[^0-9A-Za-z]+` https://regex101.com/r/TtoZ4h/1

Comment: but how to do it in code

Comment: Like `mystring.replaceAll("[^0-9A-Za-z]+", "")` but I think the posted answer is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `isLetterOrDigit` function on Char and filter required chars from the string.

```
scala> val str = "abd@1098\\jaka.kdcs"
str: String = abd@1098\jaka.kdcs

scala> str.filter(_.isLetterOrDigit)
res3: String = abd1098jakakdcs
```

Answer (score 2):

In First step you need to use regular expressions to check characters and numbers only
Example : scala> "34Az".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}")